# WordPress Scrolling Issue and White Content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm confused why when new content on this page is opened (drop downs) you can no longer scroll until you click on the page or violently scroll until it responds.

Additionally, when you scroll down the page, it seems to go completely white, and lag before the content of the page shows.

I've searched numerous topics, and I keep getting unrelated issues, I believe, such as White Screen of Death and Mobile Smooth scrolling.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have .cbp-spmenu-push { overflow-x: hidden; }, but for desktop this works fine so maybe it's your computer being too slow to load content.

Comment: No clue. Is that the problem? Lol -- I'm working on someones website, not my own. I personally wouldn't use WordPress if they paid me.

Comment: If you're trying to find a fix to this white screen, I'd say use a different computer and see if it still is a problem cause the site works fine for me.

Comment: The white screen **appears** it may have to do with WordPress's admin panel being active on the website. However the scrolling issue is apparent on 3 computers. Click a dropdown and scroll. It doesn't respond at first, you need to keep scrolling or click the page.

Comment: @WASasquatch - no need to throw condescending comments about a technology. Unhelpful, and Stack Overflow is not the place for that.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Likely deflection for a irrelevant observation, and condescending remark about my computer to slow for a basic webpage in 2019, a highly unlikely scenario for basic effects we've been using since the mid 2000s. I apologize. Though peoples opinions on software I wouldn't say is condescending, they're public entities inherently open to critique, criticism, and preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have `overflow-y: scroll` on the html element in `/wp-content/themes/nwdastore/style.css`. If you remove that, the janky scroll goes away.

Comment: *What* html element? Can you edit this through the admin panel or will I need to override the CSS? His host doesn't have FTP (I guess, or he doesn't know...). Curious what it's for and if overriding would break something else.

Comment: @WASasquatch the actual literal <html> element! If you can add CSS in the admin panel, just add this and it should fix it: 

```html {
  overflow-y: initial;
}```

Comment: That's weird. I went up as far as Body, didn't think they would apply to `HTML`. This whole theme has me confused. Thank you.